# Photoresist for PCB patterning

Tags: pcb-fabrication

Anybody has reference of the what chemicals photoresist for PCB patterning are made of?
I would like something as specific as possible. No brand names please. Peer reviewed papers would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study on thermal crosslinking reaction of **o-naphthoquinone diazides** and application to electrodeposition positive photoresist.

Authors: Kenji Miyagawa, Keisuke Naruse, Shinsuke Ohnishi, Koji Yamaguchi, Kenji Seko, Nobushige Numa and Naozumi Iwasawa

Comment: Did you mean to include a link?

Comment: Easy to find with a simple Google for the title in the anwser: [Soopa doopa long link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6THD-4344D6R-3&_user=10&_coverDate=06/30/2001&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1712755825&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=3dd4178fe4951dc37294d2f88e655626&searchtype=a). However, you'd have to shell out $31.50 to read it.